# Saving SCORM (exported from storyline 2) grades to database

Tags: php, scorm, articulate-storyline

I am currently making a lms in PHP. In the lms, the admin can upload a SCORM (1.2) file which the users will answer, and the result would be saved in the database. 
(Thought of a table in the form of: userID, scormID, grade)

I have looked through other options such as Moodle, but they don't have the features I need (even with modifications).

If it is not possible to handle SCORM, is there another format exported from storyline 2 that I can use?

Comment: Saving the score for a SCORM course should be fairly common. Are you sure Moodle doesn't do this? Is your SCORM package definitely sending this data?

Comment: i Know Moodle can save scorm grade, but it doesn't have some features that I need. I used Moodle as a test, and the SCORM worked perfectly. I want to save it in my own table to use in a self-built lms.

Comment: Typically the content is communicating with the "API" for SCORM 1.2. You'd need to write a quick SCORM Runtime API in order to support the communication from the Articulate content.  This includes designing a CMI Object that the content uses to save and retrieve values.

Have you written / exposed a API for the articulate content to communicate with?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately. this is the first time I try to handle SCORM myself. Do you have any general direction or suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a basic version of the server part required for SCORM1.2 is easy and here is a quiet long guide explaining the details: http://www.vsscorm.net/ - maybe this answers your question. I explicitly say "basic version" because there are many quirks and difficulties to handle if you'd like to support all features of SCORM and even more if you'd like to handle any kind of SCORM1.2 content.

**Edit**

I'm not well informed about storyline2, but if implementing SCORM is a practicable solution for you, here is a short abstract what you need to do:

First, you need to implement the import of the SCORM package. This is the easy part:

- Unzip the ZIP file into a public available folder
- Parse the imsmanifest.xml. The important stuff are the items and associated resources. You can create a table containing the title of the item and the entry url of the associated resource (SCO). For a simple implementation this should be enough

Second, you need to implement the runtime environment:

- You require a html wrapper containing an (i)frame loading the entry url of the SCO and the javascript object "API" which provides the SCORM functionality:

  - LMSInitialize: Setup the SCORM environment. Expects an empty string as parameter
  - LMSFinish: Terminate the session. Expects an empty string as parameter
  - LMSGetValue: Retrieve a value from the cmi data model, e.g. "cmi.core.score.raw". Attention: The returned value is always a string!
  - LMSSetValue: Set a value from the cmi data model
  - LMSCommit: Tell the LMS to store the cmi data model permanently. If you implement LMSSetValue to write the values directly to the database, you can make a stub implementation
  - LMSGetLastError: Retrieve the last error code
  - LMSGetErrorString: For a simple implementation, just return the provided error code
  - LMSGetDiagnostic: For a simple implementation, just return the provided error code
- The API holds the "cmi" data model, which holds for example the username, score, lesson status, etc.

As I said, this is just an abstract, but there is a lot of literature about this subject. Here is one more source: http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/

Comment: Never put an answer as a link to somewhere else... most of the time, the site is dead (gone offline), or even was editted to something different... you are linking to a blog or something, that neither has the answer, neither helps figuring out sources to fix the problem..

Comment: Thanks, I will pay more attention to that from now on. Nevertheless this blog has a quiet long documentation how to implement the SCORM run time environment. If this is what @or-duer is looking for, I can try to give a short introduction myself..

Comment: It is best to either show a direction for the user to research, or even writte guidelines... As I am no aware of details, I cant give them guidelines... however things like "Check [Google](www.google.com)", or writting `do operation x, y, z, then a, b, c` is the best way to go. Helping others is harder than solving the issue, because you have to understand the problem, understand not knowing about the problem, and finally pointing out a way for the person to help themselfs

Comment: Thank you all! I will look into the link, but would like some more directions to look for

Comment: I provided an edit, giving a little bit more details. I hope this is useful.